# Download all images in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I'm on Ubuntu (Linux) and need to download all images from this [website](http://da2.uib.no/cgi-win/WebBok.exe?slag=lesside&bokid=riksreg1&sideid=1&innhaldid=2&storleik=)

When I tried to just use "*.jpg" in combination with "wget"-command in a terminal I got a "403 Forbidden" error. Since the images are named "riksreg1_001.jpg" to "riksreg1_736.jpg" it should be easy to specify a download of all images, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying:

```
curl 'http://da2.uib.no/webbok/riksreg1/bilete/riksreg1_[001-369].jpg' -o "pic#1.jpg"
```

Comment: It will go through all sides from 001 up to the last (736-737) being numbered 369.

Comment: Thanks! I had to extend it to include images up to 736 in order to get it all. It looks like all odd numbers over 1 are left out.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. The sleep 1 is there in order not to be a jerk.

```
for((i = 1; i <= 736; i++)); do
    file_number=$(printf %03d $i)
    wget "http://www.example.com/stuff/riksreg1_$file_number.jpg"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below command?

```
wget http://da2.uib.no/cgi-win/WebBok.exe?slag=lesside&bokid=riksreg1&sideid=1&innhaldid=2&storleik=riksreg1_{001..736}.jpg
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, just downloaded an empty page.